# laravel既存テーブルのModelを作成するとテーブル名にsがつく

Tags: laravel

お世話になります。Laravel初心者です。
別で作成されたLaravel8のプログラムを改修しています。
DBで既存のdtb_productというテーブルがあり

php artisan make:model DtbProduct

でModelを作成しました。
コントローラーで

use App\Models\DtbProduct;

を追加し、

```
$product = DtbProduct::find(1022);
```

と実行したところ

**SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'shareef_dev.dtb_products' doesn't exist**

とエラーが出ます。
試しに

```
$product = \DB::table('dtb_product')->find(1022);
```

としたところ問題なくテーブルの内容が取得されます。

問題点は
**dtb_product → dtb_productsとsがついてしまう**点なのですが、Laravelの全ファイルを調べてもdtb_productsとsがついている部分はありませんでした。

どの辺を確認すればよいかもわからないため、お分かりの方教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。

[Laravelのドキュメント](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names) の Eloquent Model Conventions > Table Names にありました。
Model の dtb_product.php に以下の記述を追加することでうまくいきました。

```
protected $table = 'dtb_ptoduct';
```